# How to edit the apple-app-site-association file auto-generated by Firebase Dynamic Links?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

Whenever I create a new url prefix using free Google-provided domain (for example, `yourapp.page.link`). The apple-app-site-association file gets automatically created at the respective `https://yourapp.page.link/apple-app-site-association` and `https://yourapp.page.link/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`.

The generated apple-app-site-association file looks something like:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "1234567890.com.example.ios",
        "paths": [
          "NOT /_/*",
          "/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and it is redirecting all paths to my app.

**I want to exclude certain paths that should not be handled by my app.** I know I can do this by specifying `“NOT ”` in front of the path that i want to exclude in the `paths` array, but I just can't find a way to edit the auto-generated file.

Comment: have you found an answer yet to this question?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with dynamic links "hijacking" the links for email verification and password reset, forcing me to manually add exclude paths to the apple-app-site-association file. The only way forward I could find that seems to be working is to do the following:

1. Add your apple-app-site-association file to your public folder:

   - `/public/apple-app-site-association` (or whatever you have set as public folder)
   - `/public/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`
2. Add the following to the hosting section in your firebase.json (keep `"appAssociation": "AUTO"` or your dynamic links will stop working and you'll see an error message in the console.)

```
"headers": [
  {
    "source": "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association",
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Content-Type",
        "value": "application/json"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "source": "/apple-app-site-association",
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Content-Type",
        "value": "application/json"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: #Tomas May I know this custom AASA file should be in our domain or in the Firebase Hosting?

Comment: @RajeshMaurya This is related to Firebase hosting, regardless if it's your own domain or a free yourapp.page.link domain.

Comment: I got this is firebase hosting. The Step 1 should perform in Firebase hosting or at our own host server. Please suggest.